# What does “fell at recess” mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I tried searching several sources and none of them provide meaningful sense to me.

The story is the following:

I watched Stranger Things and one of the kids was bullied. Later that day the mate who met him did not know that he was bullied, and asked him what happened to his face.
The kid just said:

> “I fell at recess”

I am not sure what this means, please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster offers [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recess):

> a suspension of business or procedure often for rest or relaxation
> —*children playing at recess*

In America, the period called **recess** occurs during school and typically follows the midday meal. If the weather is not terrible, children go outdoors, usually in a large yard enclosed by a fence. Most of them play unorganized games, chat, read, etc. Some playgrounds have [equipment](https://www.ghp-news.com/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/2021/07/playground.jpg.webp) that can be climbed upon. **Falling down** is a reasonable cover for getting bullied in such a place.

As a noun, **recess** has other meanings, but to most Americans the period I have described is the default meaning.

Comment: The comment was meant to be funny. It's like saying I fell down the stairs for a black-eye when one guy punches another.

Comment: @Lambie Proving once again how important the exact context is to a question. I imagine the intonation gives it away.

Comment: It's a great show. Even though aimed originally at teens.

Comment: @Lambie we have tried the latest season, but have found it rather childish.